# Linkedin profile image url giving access denied

Tags: linkedin-api

I have used Spring social for integration with linkedin.

When the integration completes we save the users profile image which has below url:

https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQHQ0C7xKhQehg/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0?e=1527508800&v=alpha&t=vkxX_3Uw7qe8d_9ZSqPwQGpwa6nfUmkzMgEKtMdgf1g

But this url is giving access denied error. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Have the same issue, haven't figured out yet though... what api version you using v1 or v2?

Comment: @Massi we are using V1

Comment: I'm using v1 as well (v2 is premium actually) anyway I solved my issue and answered you below. Hope it fixes yours as well.

Answer (score 4):

This may help, As per https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/media-migration,

`The new id will be dynamic and can change from time to time. We recommend retrieving at least once every 60 days to update your media-typed URN.`

This could be one of the issue which you might be facing.

In order to fix this, I save the image, the moment it is received on to personal storage(AWS S3).

Comment: The link you provided is now dead.

Comment: A quick google led me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/media-migration. Check if this helps! @chris

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the URL of my picture of my In Public profile and the one returned from the API.

The picture URL in the XML returned after the `?` for params `v` and `t` had `&amp ;` instead of `&`:

e.g.
`https://media.licdn.com/.../profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0?e=152800"&amp";v=beta"&amp";t=LJTrw_oj9npH06X1u0HjQ`

Replacing it with something like:

`pictureURL = pictureURL.replaceAll("&amp ;","&");`

fixed the issue for me. 
Hope this helps

Note that there is an extra space between `&amp` and `;`. It would have formatted otherwise.